# How to include the current font name in the document

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

Using plain TeX coding, how to I include the current font name in the document? I know it involves `\the\font` but can't recall the exact method.

This is for use in a font-sampler, so that before each font sample, an appropriate title appears identifying that font.

Comment: A quick Google search for "tex show font" gives me https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109703/how-to-determine-the-font-being-used-by-a-latex-document with the command `\expandafter\show\the\font` in the first answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\fontname\font` to output the current font name in your document:

```
\def\samplefont#1{%
    % set font style and save name
    #1\edef\savedname{\fontname\font}%
    % print small sample
    {\leavevmode\tt\hbox to 1in{\savedname:\hss}}%
    abcxyz ABCXYZ 123\par
}
\samplefont\rm
\samplefont\tt
\samplefont\bf
\samplefont\it
\samplefont\sl
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From the TeXbook (p. 214)

- `\the\`⟨font⟩ produces a font identifier that selects the
  specified font. For example, ‘`\the\font`’ is a control sequence corresponding
  to the current font.

This is most useful only in `\edef`, to get an alias command for the current font:

```
{\it\xdef\thisfont{\the\font}abc}

{\thisfont abc}
```

will produce the same result.

For the external name of the current font, use `\fontname\font` (current font) or `\fontname\tenrm` (or whatever font selection command you want to use):

```
\fontname\font

\fontname\tenrm

\fontname\seveni

\bye
```

[image]